# Is it possible to create prototype cells in Interface Builder without story boards?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, storyboard

In the WWDC video "Session 309 - Introducing Interface Builder Storyboarding" the speaker adds a table view controller and creates a cell in IB that can be directly linked to outlets in the app (at about 13:30 in the video).

Can this be done without story boards and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a nib file with just a table cell in it, set the class to a custom UITableViewCell subclass, and link any cell subviews to outlets in the class.

Comment: Thanks MCannon, but I'm more curious how they did it in the session video and if it can be done without storyboarding. He simply dragged in a table view and began editing the cells right inside it.

Comment: It appears this is the case.  Back to doing things the (slightly) harder way.