# Is it true Xcode/IB DOES NOT check for protocols?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, protocols, iboutlet

Xcode5 milieu only. (Not older versions.)

1) make a new class called say Test.  it's a UIViewController

```
@interface Test:UIViewController
```

2) in storyboard, make a new screen, a UIViewController, change it to "Test"

obviously, if you add a control (say, a button) on the storyboard, you can drag it to an IBOutlet defined in Test.h.  No problem.

3) Now in Test.h add the two protocols ..

```
@interface Test:UIViewController
          <
          UICollectionViewDataSource,
          UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
          >
```

4) now in IB drag a small UICollectionView in to the view.

5) click on the collection view, connections inspector. now, **drag the delegate and dataSource to "Test"**

Everything works correctly .. **no problem**.

**However**.  Disconnect those connections.  Go back to step (3).  **Do not do** step 3.  in other words, you've "forgotten" to add the protocols to Test.

Now try step (5)

**In fact (I believe) ... it works fine.**

It seems strange to me that you can drag to a UICollectionViewDataSource (say) when, in fact, it simply is NOT a UICollectionViewDataSource (!)

(Naturally, you can't drag, say, a button anywhere there is no IBOutlet.)

(A) Does everyone else **see this behaviour**, of have I screwed up as usual?

(B) Is this perhaps a **known bug / omission**?

(C) Is there anything else I'm missing ("oh, it has to be like that because...")

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true. UIB does not check any protocol method is implemented. Even if you enabled warnings for `Incomplete Objective-C Protocols` in Build Settings for your project, its behaviour is the same.